# React Hooks Error: Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am getting this error when using the `useState` hook. I have this in it's basic form, looking at the [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) for a reference, but am still getting this error. I'm ready for the face palm moment...

```
export function Header() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
  return <span>header</span>
}
```

Comment: Works for me... no errors... did you update to 16.7?

Comment: Yeah, I did.  I'm thinking maybe it has something else to do with my setup, but I have no idea what. Event if I use that same hook at the top of the function App component, I get the same error.

Comment: Hmmm... all I did was npx create-react-app newhook and then yarn add react@next and react-dom@next and it worked just fine...

Comment: Just an FYI to anyone that ends up here, you need to update both React and ReactDOM to @next in order for hooks to work. If you don't, react will toss the above error. I know because I just had this problem and that was my solution.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

### Updated: 2018-Dec

New version of `react-hot-loader` is out now, [link](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/issues/1088#issuecomment-446938770). Hooks is now working out of the box. Thank to the author, theKashey.

Check out this boilerplate https://github.com/ReeganExE/react-hooks-boilerplate

- React Hooks
- React Hot Loader
- Webpack, Babel, ESLint Airbnb

### *Previous Answer:*

First, make sure you installed `react@next` and `react-dom@next`.

Then check for you are using `react-hot-loader` or not.

In my case, disable hot loader & HMR could get it work.

See [https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/issues/1088](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/issues/1088#issuecomment-433537974).

Quoted:

> Yes. RHL is 100% not compatible with hooks. There is just a few
>   reasons behind it:
>
> SFC are being converted to Class components. There is reason - to be
>   able to forceUpdate on HMR, as long there is no "update" method on
>   SFC. I am looking for other way of forcing the update (like this. So
>   RHL is killing SFC.
>
> "hotReplacementRender". RHL is trying to do React's job, and render
>   the old and the new app, to merge them. So, obviously, that's broken
>   now.
>
> I am going to draft a PR, to mitigate both problems. It will work, but
>   not today.

There is a more proper fix, which would work - [cold API](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader#disabling-a-type-change-%EF%B8%8F)

You may disable RHL for any custom type.

```
import { cold } from 'react-hot-loader';

cold(MyComponent);
```

Search for `"useState/useEffect"` inside component source code, and "cold" it.

### Updated:

As per [updated](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/issues/1088#issuecomment-441191107) from react-hot-loader maintainer, you could try `react-hot-loader@next` and set the config as bellow:

```
import { setConfig } from 'react-hot-loader';

setConfig({
  // set this flag to support SFC if patch is not landed
  pureSFC: true
});
```

Thank to @loganfromlogan for the update.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out :). I am using react-hot-loader, so it would make sense that it's not working. However, I'm not 100% sure yet that there isn't something else going on as well. I'll going to follow this issue on react-hot-loader, and will update this question after a fix is posted.

Comment: I can now confirm that disabling react-hot-loader has resolve this error.

Comment: To add, if by any chance you are rendering your component as an inline jsx function call, it will still cause the error, even when the component is wrapped with `cold`. So `{MyComponent(props)}` will not work, but `<MyComponent {...props} />` will.

Comment: There is a way to get this working with react-hot-loader now. Refer to this comment from the maintainer of react-hot-loader, https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/issues/1088#issuecomment-441191107

Answer (score 33):

My problem was forgetting to update `react-dom` module. [See issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13972#issuecomment-433178133).

Comment: Me too! I am using create-react-app and Typescript

Comment: I am using react and react-dom version 16.8.3 but still have same issue

Answer (score 22):

Had the same issue. My problem was related to React Router. I had accidentally used

```
<Route render={ComponentUsingHooks} />
```

instead of

```
<Route component={ComponentUsingHooks} />
```

Comment: this comment has saved my life too. Wasted 3 hours on that and ripped my project to pieces. Was a typo in the router

Comment: I was rendering the component as a child inside the Route element as `<Route>{component}</Route>` and the solution did the trick

Comment: Just spent my entire afternoon on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve this by importing React's primitive hooks in the component file, then passing them into my custom hooks. For some reason, the error only occurs when I import the React hook (like useState) in my custom hook file.

I'm importing useState in my component file:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'; // import useState

import {useCustomHook} from '../hooks/custom-hook'; // import custom hook

const initialState = {items: []};
export default function MyComponent(props) {
    const [state, actions] = useCustomHook(initialState, {useState});
    ...
}
```

Then in my hook file:

```
// do not import useState here

export function useCustomHook(initialValue, {useState}) {
    const [state, setState] = useState(initialValue || {items: []});

    const actions = {
        add: (item) => setState(currentState => {
            const newItems = currentState.items.concat([item]);
            return {
                ...currentState,
                items: newItems,
            };
        }),
    };

    return [state, actions];
}
```

This method has improved the testability of my hooks because I don't need to mock React's library to provide the primitive hooks. Instead, we can pass in a mock `useState` hook right into the custom hook's function. I think this improves code quality, as your custom hooks now have no coupling with the React library, allowing for more natural functional programming and testing.

Answer (score 3):

I experienced this error while using [Parcel's Hot Module Replacement](https://parceljs.org/hmr.html), and fixed by updating `react-dom` to it's alpha version:

```
yarn add react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0
```

[See this issue.](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13972#issuecomment-433178133)

Answer (score 3):

I had a problem in a monorepo, where a package [docz](https://github.com/pedronauck/docz) used `react@16.6.3` and the final output bundle had two react versions.

[Issue on Github](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14262)

Fixed it by removing the package

Answer (score 3):

Just to elaborate on @rista404's answer, including **duplicate versions** of `react` (and perhaps `react-dom`) will yield the same error depending on where you are using your hooks. Here are two examples...

1. An external dependency includes another version of `react` in its `dependencies`, likely by mistake as `react` should usually be a peer dependency. If `npm` doesn't automatically dedupe this version with your local version, you may see this error. This is what @rista404 was referring to.
2. You `npm link` a package that includes `react` in its `devDependencies` or `dependencies`. Now, for modules in this package, you may see errors if they pull a different version of `react` from the their local `node_modules` directory rather than the parent project's.

The latter can be fixed when bundling with `webpack` by using `resolve.alias` like so...

```js
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'react': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/react'),
            'react-dom': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/react-dom')
        }
    }
```

This will ensure `react` is always pulled from the parent project's `node_modules` directory.

Comment: I was in the second case. Really, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Another solution if you are running into this when using npm link:

You can `npm link` react in your library as explained here:
https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html#duplicate-react

or set react in your library as peerDependency and then use `npm link --only=production`

Answer (score 2):

The problem for me was indeed [react-hot-loader](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/issues/1088#issuecomment-434087118).

You can **disable react-hot-loader for a single component** instead of the entire app using the `cold` method like this:

```
import { cold } from 'react-hot-loader'

export const YourComponent = cold(() => {

  // ... hook code

  return (
    // ...
  )
})
```

OR

```
export default cold(YourComponent)
```

Answer (score 2):

My issue was the following:

I was doing:
`ReactDOM.render(Example(), app);`

Whereas I should have been doing:
`ReactDOM.render(<Example />, app);`

Comment: This was my problem as well, & I'm glad to find it among the answers here.

Comment: This was my problem as well, & I'm glad to find it among the answers here.

I suspected it would be some some subtle stupidity of my own cause, but because there clearly are some [real issues with duplication of modules](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13991) [in bundlers](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/3971), I went down a 4-hour rabbit hole of research rage. Happy to restore my sanity at the expense of my pride.

Comment: One thing to note is that if you don't want to use JSX you'd do it like this: `ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Example, {}), app) `

Answer (score 2):

For those who come across this issue when using MobX and wrapping a component with an `observer`, make sure you use `mobx-react-lite` instead of `mobx-react`.

**MAY 29 UPDATE**

From `mobx-react` `6.0.0` onward, [hook based components are now supported by mobx-react](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#600), thus, there is no need for `mobx-react-lite` usage anymore (if that was your problem).

Answer (score 2):

### JUNE 2021 ANSWER

I've been experiencing this problem with the **react-electron-boilerplate** app.

Many plugins and libraries like Material-UI couldn't be used in my project because of this unfortunate error and after searching a lot, I could solve the problem:

I just upgraded the `react` and `react-dom` to their latest versions.

This command got the job done!

```
yarn add react@latest react-dom@latest
```

Answer (score 1):

found this workaround for `react-hot-loader` while that PR to fix it is inbound.

Wrap the function that calls hooks in a `React.memo`, preventing a hot reload if it's unchanged.

`const MyFunc = React.memo(({props}) => {...`

Credit for solution: 
https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/9489

Answer (score 1):

For fellow users of yarn workspaces, here's my situation and how I figured it out.

- packages

  - foo

    - react@16.8.6
  - bar

    - react@16.10.1

The Facebook docs on [Invalid Hook Call Warning](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html) say nothing about yarn workspaces, so I assumed my config was correct. But it wasn't. You can fix the error only by using the same version across **all your packages**.

In the example above, you have to bump the version of react from "foo" to 16.10.1, so that it matches the react version from "bar".

Bonus: [see this discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13991) for a beautiful collection of emotional baggage offloaded on the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

Well in my Case i was calling useSelector inside useEffect !!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Create React App, you have to update `"react-scripts"` version also with react and react-dom version.

```
 "react-scripts": "2.1.5",
 "react": "^16.8.1",
 "react-dom": "^16.8.1",
```

this combination works fine.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was occurring because I had a new version of react (16.8.6) and an old version of react-dom (16.6.1).

https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html#mismatching-versions-of-react-and-react-dom

Upgrading both to @latest (16.8.6) fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

Check `react` and `react-dom` versions are **strictly equal**. Take care of the circumflex `^` symbol on versions.

`"17.0.0"` could not be the same as `"^17.0.0"`

npm - Carret Ranges: https://github.com/npm/node-semver#caret-ranges-123-025-004
React - Changelog: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md

That's one of the reasons to better install packages with -E or --save-exact

```sh
npm install --save --save-exact <package@vesion>
```

Answer (score -5):

update package.json react-dom version as react

Comment: "react": "^16.7.0-alpha.0",
"react-dom": "^16.7.0-alpha.0",

Comment: If answer is just suggestion, You can use comment section