# Error importing custom hooks in React 16.7.0-alpha

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

Been playing around with the new hook RFC in react and can't get my custom hook working properly. Not sure if what is going on is on my end or a bug with the React alpha itself.

I've been trying to create a click outside hook. I was able to get it working with this code.

#### ./dropdown_builtin_hooks

```
const DropDownWrapper = React.memo(props => {
  const { user, className } = props;
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleDOMClick = event => {
      console.log(event.target);
      if (active && !!ref && !(event.target === ref.current || ref.current.contains(event.target))) {
        console.log("Clicked outside of wrapped component");
        setActive(false);
      }
    };
    window.addEventListener("click", handleDOMClick);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("click", handleDOMClick);
    };
  });

  const handleDropDown = (): void => {
    setActive(true);
  };

  return (
    <div ref={ref} className={className} >
      <Toggler onClick={handleDropDown}>
        {active ? (
          <StyledDropUpArrow height="1.5em" filled={false} />
        ) : (
          <StyledDropDownArrow height="1.5em" filled={false} />
        )}
      </Toggler>
      {active && (
        <DropDown/>
      )}
    </div>
  );
});

export default DropDownWrapper;
```

However when I try to wrap this in a custom hook that I can reuse and import it into my component. Something like this...

#### ./hooks

```
export function useClickedOutside<RefType = any>(
  initialState: boolean = false,
): [React.RefObject<RefType>, boolean, Function] {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  const [active, setActive] = useState(initialState);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleDOMClick = event => {
      console.log(event.target);
      if (active && !!ref && !(event.target === ref.current || ref.current.contains(event.target))) {
        console.log("Clicked outside of wrapped component");
        setActive(false);
      }
    };
    window.addEventListener("click", handleDOMClick);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("click", handleDOMClick);
    };
  });
  return [ref, active, setActive];
}
```

#### ./dropdown_custom_hook

```
const DropDownWrapper = React.memo(props => {
  const { user, className } = props;
  const [ref, active, setActive] = useClickedOutside(false);

  const handleDropDown = (): void => {
    setActive(true);
  };

  return (
    <div ref={ref} className={className} >
      <Toggler onClick={handleDropDown}>
        {active ? (
          <StyledDropUpArrow height="1.5em" filled={false} />
        ) : (
          <StyledDropDownArrow height="1.5em" filled={false} />
        )}
      </Toggler>
      {active && (
        <DropDown/>
      )}
    </div>
  );
});

export default DropDownWrapper;
```

**At first I figured it was an issue with hot reloading, but after removing that I am still getting this error:**

> Uncaught Error: Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function
>   component.

I only get this issue when I use imports and exports. If I copy the same custom hook function and paste it above my component it works properly.

I assume I'm doing something dumb or haven't read the docs well enough.

Cheers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Hooks Error: Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53028117/react-hooks-error-hooks-can-only-be-called-inside-the-body-of-a-function-compon)

Comment: That was my first issue, but as I said I already removed that and got it working without a custom hook. I was also using an alias to import the hook, but removing that didn't seem to fix the issue either

Comment: yep, sorry, missed that you have already checked that

Comment: so for import/export way you are using `useEffect`, `useRef` right in your function but outside functional component. I believe you just cannot do that this way. So you need to recompose reusable part in different way to contain just business logic but not interaction between different hooks.

Comment: Just an FYI to anyone that ends up here, you need to update both React and ReactDOM to @next in order for hooks to work. If you don't, react will toss the above error. I know because I just had this problem and that was my solution.

Comment: Haha I almost felt really dumb for a second, luckily both `react` and `react` dom are the right version. Did some more playing last night when I got back from the office, and that code worked in a new react project. I'm figuring that there's an issue with one of my project dependencies.

Comment: Well I'm at a loss now. I believe there's an issue with `styled-components` and `typescript`, but I can't replicate this bug except in my codebase. I used the newly released `typescript create-react-app` and added `styled-components`, but it works there. I think there must be something in my `babelrc` or `webpack configs`  that is causing the issue. My gut tells me it relates to this [issue or the other referenced](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14008) but I can't replicate the bug in a sandbox to make my an issue 

Comment: Seems to be working fine. See sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/y7k4o2q79x