# react i18next "hooks" error when using t() from useTranslation()

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, i18next, react-i18next

I am using React-i18next library and I need to get a translation function `t()` inside of a function.

```
export function translateCell(cell) {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  return (t(cell));
}
```

When using `useTranslation()` it fails with error

> Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component.

I tried to use `I18nextProvider` and also `.use(initReactI18next)` in initialization, but both setups produces same error.

Am I using it the wrong way, or have I misunderstood something?

**EDIT:**
I found out, that only functions, that will be rendered as component can use useTranslation. Like

```
function export MyComponent (cell) {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  return (<div>{t(cell)}</div>);
}
...
render(){
<MyComponent/>
```

Comment: you should find a solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53028117/react-hooks-error-hooks-can-only-be-called-inside-the-body-of-a-function-compon

Comment: @samb102 I am not using react-hot-loader, which is mentioned in that post. And even when I added it to my project, it did not solved anything :-/

Comment: did u try updating `react-dom` ?

Comment: Sure, my versions are latest:   "react": "^16.8.4", "react-dom": "^16.8.4", "react-i18next": "^10.3.0", "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1", "react-scripts": "^2.1.8"

Comment: @MichalČervenka Same issue here.. Strange that they have this example on their website: https://react.i18next.com/getting-started

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: `const { t } = useTranslation(); ` can be called only in component = function which will be called in HTML tree: `<MyComponent/>`. Than it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution in exporting i18n object after inicialization and use that at all other places which I need.

**file i18nSetup.js**:

```
i18n
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .init({
        resources: translationResources,
        interpolation: {
            escapeValue: false 
        }
    });

export default i18n;
```

**In other files**:

```
import i18n from "../functions/i18nSetup";

export function translateCell(cell) {
  return (i18n.t(cell));
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. `t` is not a function of `i18n`.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
import { Trans } from 'react-i18next';
```

and use it like this:

```
<Trans>word-key</Trans>
```

https://react.i18next.com/guides/quick-start