# Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component

Tags: firebase, react-native

I'm trying to implement Firebase Notification in my RN App. I followed this [post](https://www.codementor.io/@uokesita/react-native-push-notifications-with-firebase-2019-10on0z19t6)

But when I run the code, I'm getting `Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component`. There's my **App.json** file

```
export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
  isLoadingComplete: false,
};

  render() {
     return (
       <SafeAreaView forceInset={{ bottom: 'never'}} style={styles.container}>
         {Platform.OS === 'ios' && <StatusBar barStyle="default" />}
         <Provider store={store}>
         <AppNavigator/>
         </Provider>
       </SafeAreaView>
     );
  }
```

And functions to get the token, permissions and show alert with the remote notification. Are these functions in right place?

```
  useEffect(() => {
    this.checkPermission();
    this.messageListener();
   }, []);

   checkPermission = async () => {
    const enabled = await firebase.messaging().hasPermission();
    if (enabled) {
      this.getFcmToken();
    } else {
      this.requestPermission();
    }
   }

   getFcmToken = async () => {
    const fcmToken = await firebase.messaging().getToken();
    if (fcmToken) {
     console.log(fcmToken);
     this.showAlert("Your Firebase Token is:", fcmToken);
    } else {
     this.showAlert("Failed", "No token received");
    }
   }

   requestPermission = async () => {
    try {
     await firebase.messaging().requestPermission();
     // User has authorised
    } catch (error) {
      // User has rejected permissions
    }
   }

   messageListener = async () => {
    this.notificationListener = firebase.notifications().onNotification((notification) => {
      const { title, body } = notification;
      this.showAlert(title, body);
    });

    this.notificationOpenedListener = firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened((notificationOpen) => {
      const { title, body } = notificationOpen.notification;
      this.showAlert(title, body);
    });

    const notificationOpen = await firebase.notifications().getInitialNotification();
    if (notificationOpen) {
      const { title, body } = notificationOpen.notification;
      this.showAlert(title, body);
    }

    this.messageListener = firebase.messaging().onMessage((message) => {
     console.log(JSON.stringify(message));
    });
   }

   showAlert = (title, message) => {
    Alert.alert(
     title,
     message,
     [
      {text: "OK", onPress: () => console.log("OK Pressed")},
     ],
     {cancelable: false},
    );
   }
}
```

I have no ideia what I'm missing. Maybe some function out of scope...But I can't figure out

Comment: I discovered that the problem is with   useEffect function

Comment: As the error mentions, hooks can only be used in a functional component. Your component is a class and thus hooks do not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Hooks Error: Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53028117/react-hooks-error-hooks-can-only-be-called-inside-the-body-of-a-function-compon)

Answer (score 0):

I changed useEffect to `componentDidMount()` and It worked great

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.checkPermission();
  this.messageListener();
}
```