# Typescript Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am converting an React project from JS to Typescript. To organize the code I am using Function Components with custom hook functions to fetch the data as shown below. However, upon using these functions am always getting the above trivial error. I have found the official react page about mismatching version of react but it seems not the case in my situation (https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html) . Any idea what might be the problem?

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const usePostItemService = () => {
  const [result, setResult] = useState<>({
    status: 'loading'
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => setResult({ status: 'loaded', payload: response }))
      .catch(error => setResult({ status: 'error', error }));
  }, []);

  return result;
};

export default usePostItemService;
```

The above custom hook is simply called in function component as below:

```
const Items: React.FC<{}> = () => {
  const service = usePostItemService();

  return (
    <div>
     Hello
    </div>
  );
};

export default Items;
```

The dependencies are currently set as follows:

```
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-dom": "^16.13.1",
"react-router-dom": "^5.1.2"
```

Comment: Do you use a monorepository or `npm link`ed packages?

Comment: I am not sure how to check this ... all i do is after creating a react ts project, run yarn start or if i have to install package yarn add ....

Comment: Your case is a bit of an anomaly, I'm sure it's project related and not scoped down to this issue. Have you made sure this isn't the case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54922959/2111515

Comment: How is Items rendered?

Comment: @HMR for simplicity i have ommited the return div as it is bit heavy...

Comment: @BarryMichaelDoyle will try to downgrade from 16.13.1 to 16.8.1 although it does feel awkward

Comment: @Jim The link I provided doesn't say anything about downgrading React versions.

Comment: No, my question was: how is items rendered? Are you rendering it like `<Items {...props} />` or `{Items(props)}` or some other way.

Comment: @BarryMichaelDoyle sorry i accidentally scrolled down . This is how i use it with Route:
<Route exact path="/" component={props => <Items {...props} />} />

Comment: Both, i have created new solution and copied over the files. This solved the issue, Most likely this issue is caused by libraries version conflicts. Generally speaking however my impression is that Typescript is bit immature and much more flimsy compared to vanila JS. Productivity wise i have yet to see an improvement.