# "Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component" problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I get an error in the console as

> error!! [Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of
> the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the
> following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app*

```
   import firebase from '../../database/firebase';
   import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
   import * as actions from "../../store/actions";

    export const userProfilePcture =(id)=>{
       const image = firebase.storage().ref(id + '/profilePicture');
       var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
       image.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
       user.updateProfile({
          photoURL: url
        }).then(() =>{
          console.log("updete succefully");
          updeteUser();
        }).catch(error =>{
         console.log("error!!",error);
        });
    
      });


      };

       export const updeteUser=()=>{
       const dispatch=useDispatch();
       var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
       dispatch(actions.updateUser(user));
     }
```

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56663785/invalid-hook-call-hooks-can-only-be-called-inside-of-the-body-of-a-function-com)

Comment: In the above post, you can find the link for documentation about the hooks. Your component should be a proper functional component (starting with a capital letter) or it should start with `use`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Hooks Error: Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53028117/react-hooks-error-hooks-can-only-be-called-inside-the-body-of-a-function-compon)

Answer (score 1):

This is the hook you are using:

```
const dispatch=useDispatch();
```

You can only use hooks inside a React functional component. Right now you are trying to use this hook in a normal javascript function.