# Invalid hook call when setting up context with a reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm trying to setup an `AppProvider` component that uses a context and reducer to handle global data for my app. However it looks like the `useReducer` hook that is called within `AppProvider` is causing an error. I've read [the link in the error message](https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call) and as far as I can tell I'm not violating any of the rules listed there.

```js
import { merge } from 'lodash';
import React, { useReducer, Reducer, useContext, Dispatch } from 'react';

export interface AppState {
  stuff: string;
}
const initialState: AppState = { stuff: 'something' };
const AppStateContext = React.createContext(initialState);

export type Action = { type: 'SET_STATE'; state: Partial<AppState> };
const AppDispatchContext = React.createContext<Dispatch<Action>>(
  () => initialState,
);
const reducer: Reducer<AppState, Action> = (
  state: AppState,
  action: Action,
): AppState => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_STATE':
      return { ...merge(state, action.state) };
    default:
      return { ...state };
  }
};

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
export type AppProviderProps = AppState & { children: any };
export const AppProvider = ({ children, ...rest }: AppProviderProps) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {
    ...initialState,
    ...rest,
  });

  return (
    <AppDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
      <AppStateContext.Provider value={state}>
        {children}
      </AppStateContext.Provider>
    </AppDispatchContext.Provider>
  );
};

// Hooks
export const useAppContextState = (): AppState => useContext(AppStateContext);
export const useAppContextDispatch = (): React.Dispatch<Action> =>
  useContext(AppDispatchContext);
```

I'm using it with a new app created `with create-react-app`:

```
import queryString from 'query-string';
import React from 'react';

import { AppProvider } from './app/AppProvider';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const { stuff } = queryString.parse(document.location.search);

  if (typeof stuff !== 'string') {
    return (
      <div>
        Missing stuff parameter.
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <AppProvider stuff={stuff}>
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <p>
            Edit <code>src/App.tsx</code> and save to reload.
          </p>
          <a
            className="App-link"
            href="https://reactjs.org"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            Learn React
          </a>
        </header>
      </div>
    </AppProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The error thrown:

[image: error]

Package versions:

- `react@17.0.2` (the only version installed)
- `react-dom@17.0.2`
- `react-scripts@4.0.3`

Comment: Go through this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53028117/react-hooks-error-hooks-can-only-be-called-inside-the-body-of-a-function-compon It may help

Comment: How do you use `AppProvider`?

Comment: The problematic code might be where you are using `<AppProvider>`. Can you show this code?

Comment: I'm using it inside the `App` component of a new create-react-app. Edited to add the `App` component.

Comment: use `{ children: ReactNode }` and you can remove the eslint-disable

Answer (score 1):

The issue was in fact caused by having two different `react` packages installed. The app was part of a monorepo and yarn hoisted the `react-dom` package. The fix was to simply prevent hoisting `react` and `react-dom`:

In `package.json`:

```json
{
  "workspaces": {
    "packages": [
      "packages/*"
    ],
    "nohoist": [
      "**/react",
      "**/react/**",
      "**/react-dom",
      "**/react-dom/**",
    ]
  }
}
```