# Invalid hooks call - React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm new to react native and implementing a flat list. Inside render item of flat list I'm rendering a functional component and I want to use state to change an image if the user selects or deselects it.

The issue I'm facing is that is throws invalid hooks call. I'm tried all the tutorials but it shows the exact same way for describing the state.

```
const NewsItem = (props, item, onFavouriteSelect, index) => {

const[isFavourite,setFavourite] = useState(false);

return<Text>Random text for stackoverflow</Text>

}
```

Flat List Code:

```
render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    {this.state.newsList.length > 0 ? (
      <FlatList
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        data={this.state.newsList}
        renderItem={({item, index}) =>
          NewsItem(
            this.props,
            item,
            this.onFavouriteSelect.bind(this),
            index,
            this.state.isFavourite,
          )
        }
      />
    ) : (
      <LoadingScreen />
    )}
  </View>
);
}
```

Versions of react, react dom and react native are mentioned below:

```
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-dom": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.67.2",
```

Error it throws is:

```
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. 
This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

Thank you.

Updated Code:

```
class HomeScreen extends Component {
state = {
newsList: [],
IdsList: [],
isFavourite: false,
};

isFavouriteItem(index) {
if (this.state.IdsList.indexOf(index) === -1) {
  return false;
} else {
  return true;
}
}

render(){
return(){

 <FlatList
   showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
   data={this.state.newsList}
   renderItem={({item, index}) =>
          NewsCell(
            this.props,
            item,
            this.onFavouriteSelect.bind(this),
            index,
            this.isFavouriteItem(index),
            this.state.isFavourite,
          )
        }
      />

      }}
```

The updated code I've added now works. But is this a good approach?

Comment: please share your complete code with flatlist

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Hooks Error: Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53028117/react-hooks-error-hooks-can-only-be-called-inside-the-body-of-a-function-compon)

Comment: I've added the flat list code. Please take a look @NooruddinLakhani

Answer (score 0):

Use this way

```
import NewsItem from './NewsItem';

renderItem={({item, index}) =>
          <NewsItem 
            props={this.props} 
            item={item}
            onFavouriteSelect={this.onFavouriteSelect}
            index={index}
            isFavourite={this.state.isFavourite},
          )
        }


const NewsItem = ({props, item, onFavouriteSelect, index}) => {

  const[isFavourite,setFavourite] = useState(false);

  return<Text>Random text for stackoverflow</Text>

}
export default NewsItem;
```

Comment: This still is showing the error. I'm updating the code please take a look

Comment: @Umar It i showing error because you are using functional component in class base component. Create separate component for Flatlist Item in another file name like `NewsItem.js` and past your code there as I did and try

Comment: From the start, I had a separate file "NewsItem" but wherever I add useState it always shows error.

Comment: @Umar Have you import useState?

Comment: yes. I've imported useState
import React,{useState} from 'react';

Answer (score -1):

Instead of calling `const[isFavourite,setFavourite] = useState(false);` inside `NewsItem`, call useState in top-level of your function component.

```
const NewsItem = (props, item, onFavouriteSelect, index) => {

    const[isFavourite,setFavourite] = useState(false); //remove this line and place in top-level of your function

  return<Text>Random text for stackoverflow</Text>

}
```

Ref : [Breaking the Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html#breaking-the-rules-of-hooks)

Comment: I've created a separate file for "NewsItem" and this is the start of the function.
I'm calling this on renderItem of "Flat List". I've also added the flat list code. Please check again and point out the issue in the code. Thank you.

Comment: If your updated code works without additional effort then, it's fine